# Do people who are born in dwija castes did lots of virtues in their previous lives?

Tags: caste-system, moksha, rebirth

Is it true that those who born in twice-born castes (Brahmin , Kshatriya and Vaishya) did lots of virtues (Punyas) in their previous lives ?

I am asking this as in the past only twice born castes had the access to Hindu scriptures and studying hindu scriptures is essential to get Moksha.

Also in some hindu scriptures it is written that only dwija men can read any scriptures as other people have committed sins in their previous lives.

Although in present time , even non-dwija castes and foreigners can read the hindu scriptures . So,this thing may not be applicable in present time , at least not in a strict way.

Comment: For the last part of ur question..If everyone start doing a crime it does not mean that it's okay. It's still a crime. Similarly, even if non dwijas are reading the scriptures which is NOT for them, it does not mean that the rule is not applicable now. The rule is still there but people don't follow it.

Comment: @LSSJBroly But many people including foreigners have read the Hindu scriptures and have learnt the Hindu philosophy and they have benefited a lot from it.  How can you explain it ? They are certainly more spiritual , religious than many dwija Hindu men.  They are certainly on correct spiritual path.

Comment: @LSSJBroly Also most dwija men in present times , themselves are following the dharma of shudra as they work for wage(a shudra attribute) . Then how those dwija-men have right to read the scriptures ?

Comment: Those foreigners who did everything according to rules got the spiritual benefit...Also, even if someone is allowed to read or not...anyone who reads something good definitely there will be change in that person. Not every scripture demands dwija. But scriptures which are for Dwijas like the Vedas are not to be read by Everyone. Other people listen to it by Brahmanas. People can even get spirituality by reading BG and other geetas properly. Moreover, I'm talking about real 'Dwijas' ... And not somebody who does not follow anything and is just born in a particular caste or varna.

Answer (score 0):

yes,of course. in gita chapter 8 shloka 6 it has been said that the thought that will arise at the time of death by a living entity he or she will get that type of birth. those who dies in sattva guna gets higher birth in next life. those who dies in rajo guna gets similar birth and those who die in tamo guna they get lower birth.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely true. Hence this birth utilises the happiness out of early beings and materials of existence.
The twice born tries to enjoy/ appreciate varieties of beings on Earth and is not going to have more repeated births & deaths based on karma on Earth.